# JUnit 5 - Como executar um método de teste apenas se outro método de teste passar?

Tags: java, junit

Seria algo assim:

```
@Test
void metodo1() { assertTrue(...); }

@Test
void metodo2() { //Deve ser executado após método1(), e SOMENTE SE metodo1() passou!
   assertTrue(...); 
}
```

Eu preciso fazer isso para os casos onde nem faz sentido rodar um "metodo2()" se o teste do "metodo1()" falhou; são casos em que o "metodo2()" chegaria a receber exceptions para as quais não quero prepará-lo para receber. Exemplo com calculadora:

```
class TestCalculadora {
    private Calculadora calc = new Calculadora();
    @Test void nao_deve_lancar_exception_ao_tentar_dividir_por_zero() {
        try { calc.calcular("3/0"); } 
        catch(Exception e) { fail("lançou '"+e.getMessage()+"'"); }
    }
    @Test void deve_retornar_um_resultado_apos_tentar_dividir_por_zero() {
        assertNotNull(calc.calcular("3/0"));
    }
    @Test void deve_retornar_uma_msg_de_erro_apos_tentar_dividir_por_zero() {
        Resultado r = calc.calcular("3/0");
        String msgDeErro = r.getMensagem();
        assertEquals(msgDeErro, "Impossível Dividir por Zero!");
    }
    @Test void nao_deve_retornar_numero_apos_tentar_dividir_por_zero() {
        Resultado r = calc.calcular("3/0");
        BigDecimal num = r.getNumResultante();
        assertNull(num);
    }
}
```

Veja nesse exemplo que os métodos `deve_retornar_uma_msg_de_erro_apos_tentar_dividir_por_zero()` e `nao_deve_retornar_numero_apos_tentar_dividir_por_zero()` não deveriam ser executados (deveriam ser ignorados) caso um dos métodos `nao_deve_lancar_exception_ao_tentar_dividir_por_zero()` e/ou `deve_retornar_um_resultado_apos_tentar_dividir_por_zero()` falhem, caso contrário, eles irão lançar uma NullPointerException se `calcular("3/0")` retornar null ou irão receber um Exception lançada por esse método `calcular` que eles não esperam receber.

Como lidar com isso? Existe uma forma já prevista pelo JUnit 5 para lidar com essas situações?

Comment: Parece-me que você não está usando o JUnit do jeito que ele foi feito para funcionar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível fazer isso utilizando o TestNG. O TestNG é um framework de teste que é feito em cima do Junit. Para mais detalhes ver documentação: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Tem duas formas de fazer isso com o TestNG:

1 - Utilizar o `dependsOnMethods`

```
@Test 
public void nao_deve_lancar_exception_ao_tentar_dividir_por_zero() {
    try { calc.calcular("3/0"); } 
    catch(Exception e) { fail("lançou '"+e.getMessage()+"'"); }
}
@Test
public void deve_retornar_um_resultado_apos_tentar_dividir_por_zero() {
    assertNotNull(calc.calcular("3/0"));
}
@Test(dependsOnMethods= {"nao_deve_lancar_exception_ao_tentar_dividir_por_zero"}) 
public void deve_retornar_uma_msg_de_erro_apos_tentar_dividir_por_zero() {
    Resultado r = calc.calcular("3/0");
    String msgDeErro = r.getMensagem();
    assertEquals(msgDeErro, "Impossível Dividir por Zero!");
}
@Test(dependsOnMethods= {"deve_retornar_um_resultado_apos_tentar_dividir_por_zero"}) 
public void nao_deve_retornar_numero_apos_tentar_dividir_por_zero() {
    Resultado r = calc.calcular("3/0");
    BigDecimal num = r.getNumResultante();
    assertNull(num);
}
```

Esse `@Test` foi importado do TestNG: `import org.testng.annotations.Test;`. Os asserts continuam sendo do Junit. O `dependsOnMethods` recebe uma lista de testes que precisam passar para que o teste subjacente seja executado.

Se um dos testes que estão no `dependsOnMethods` falhar, será dado um skip no teste subjacente.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A outra forma é utilizando o `dependsOnGroups`. Imagine que você tem um conjunto de testes que precisam executar antes de um outro conjunto de testes. Nesse caso, o TestNG permite colocar o primeiro conjunto de testes em um grupo e depois dizer que o segundo grupo depende do primeiro.

```
@Test(groups= {"primeirosTestes"})
public void test1() {

}
@Test(groups= {"primeirosTestes"})
public void test2() {
    fail();
}
@Test(dependsOnGroups= {"primeirosTestes"})
public void test3() {

}
@Test(dependsOnGroups= {"primeirosTestes"})
public void test4() {

}
```

Se você estiver utilizando o eclipse, será necessário adicionar um plugin para poder executar os testes da mesma forma que é feita no Junit:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de instalado, os testes podem ser executados da mesma forma do Junit, mas ao invés de clicar em "Run as Junit Test", você irá clicar em "Run as TestNG Test". Não sei como é a configuração em outras IDEs.

Answer (score 8):

Você deve pensar que no seu exemplo da calculadora você descreveu 4 testes. Razoável pensar assim, né? Até o JUnit vai falar isso. Mas você fez apenas 1 teste.

## Escrevendo casos de teste

Todo caso de teste deveria ser composto de 3 partes básicas:

1. dados sendo testados
2. operações a serem realizados nesses dados
3. aferições de resultados esperados

Eu costumo resumir assim:

- dados
- operações
- aferições

Um mesmo conjunto de dados sofrendo as mesmas operações deve sofrer todas as aferições possíveis dentro do mesmo `@Test`.

Vale ressaltar também que cada caso de teste deveria ser basicamente uma unidade independente das demais anotadas com `@Test`. No máximo dependente de `@Before` ou cujos efeitos colaterais são desfeitos no `@After`. Isso significa que cada caso de teste deveria ser feito de maneira totalmente isolada dos demais, de modo que eles não estejam acoplados temporalmente, onde a execução de um precede a do outro.

### Modelando o seu caso de teste

No seu caso, temos como dados:

1. a calculadora devidamente construída
2. a expressão `"3/0"`

A operação é:

1. obter o `Resultado` da chamada de `calculadora.calcular(expressao)`

E as aferições:

1. mensagem de erro no resultado:

   ```
   String msgDeErro = r.getMensagem();
   assertEquals(msgDeErro, "Impossível Dividir por Zero!");
   ```
2. número resultante nulo:

   ```
   BigDecimal num = r.getNumResultante();
   assertNull(num);
   ```

Assim, seus 4 métodos de teste são reduzidos para apenas um teste:

```
@Test
public void dividindoPorZero() {
  // dados 
  Calculadora calc = new Calculadora();
  String expr = "3/0";

  // operações 
  Resultado r = calc.calcular(expr);

  // aferições 
  String msgDeErro = r.getMensagem(); // isso já verifica se 'r' é nulo, lançando NPE caso seja
  assertEquals(msgDeErro, "Impossível Dividir por Zero!");
  assertNull(r.getNumResultante)(
}
```

Muito mais *clean*, não acha? Sem falar que mais elegante também, levando em conta a modelagem.

### Modelando exceções

Existem situações na qual o código deve lançar uma exceção. E pronto. Quem modelou o programa o fez para lançar uma exceção durante uma operação, por algum motivo (se fez certo ou errado a nível de conceito ou performance são outros quinhentos, mas se para funcionar deve ser garantida a exceção, então a situação que a dispara precisa ser testada).

Por exemplo, a linguagem Java prevê o lançamento de `NullPointerException` em diversos casos. Entre eles, chamar método de um objeto nulo. Como isso pode ser averiguado? Criando expectativas!

Por exemplo, posso ter esses dois casos de teste, um para lançar exceção e o outro para não lançar exceção:

1. Não lança exceção:

   - dado: string com o valor `"abc"`
   - operação: chamar o método `.toString()`
   - aferição: chegou no final
2. Lança exceção

   - dado: string nula
   - operação: chamar o método `.toString()`
   - aferição: lançou a exceção específica `NullPointerException`

```
@Test
public void naoLancaExcecao() {
  // dado
  String a = "abc";
  // operação 
  a.toString();
  // aferição implícita, precisa não lançar exceção 
}

@Test(expect = NullPointerException.class)
public void lancaExcecao() {
  // dado
  String a = null;
  // operação 
  a.toString();
  // aferição implícita, precisa lançar exceção do tipo NullPointerException
}
```

Se você criar uma expectativa que não é atendida, o JUnit marca como erro. Se você não criar expectativas e explodir uma exceção, JUnit também marca como um erro.

### Execução condicional

Creio que você cria que estava neste problema. Mas não, você não estava. Nesse caso, você simplesmente não faz as operações/aferições desnecessárias.

Recentemente onde trabalho precisei implementar 36 casos de teste: 36 conjuntos de dados distintos (4 variáveis: 3 estados, 3 estados, booleano, booleano) e 1 operação possível para cada um desses conjuntos de dados.

A classe em questão tinha dois métodos: um que dizia se o método principal deveria ser executado e o método principal. Obviamente, se o método principal não deveria ser executado, eu não o executava. E a execução do método principal tinha 3 comportamentos possíveis: lança exceção A, lança exceção B ou executa limpo.

Eu criei um método auxiliar para criar o conjunto de dados (era bem simples, simples o suficiente para eu não precisar criar um caso de teste para testar meu utilitário de teste). Vou exemplificar aqui 3 possíveis casos de teste (variáveis que não são exibidas a criação foram criadas no `@Before`):

```
@Test
public void naoExecuta() {
  Dados d1 = criaDados(Enum.Tipo1, Enum.tipo1, true, true);
  assertFalse(myObj.estahAtivo(d1));
}

@Test(expect = MyExceptionB.class)
public void cabum() {
  Dados d1 = criaDados(Enum.Tipo1, Enum.tipo3, true, true);

  assertTrue(myObj.estahAtivo(d1));
  myObj.metodoExplosivo(d1);
}

@Test
public void naoExolode() {
  Dados d1 = criaDados(Enum.Tipo1, Enum.tipo3, true, false);

  assertTrue(myObj.estahAtivo(d1));
  myObj.metodoExplosivo(d1);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigrado pela resposta, sou novo com os testes e você esclareceu muito as coisas! Acho que você precisa dar uma revisada nos métodos de teste do exemplo toString(): o debaixo não se chamaria "lancaExcecao" e a aferição dele não seria _explícita_ já que o método declara esperar uma Exception?

Comment: Mas fiquei com duvida a respeito dos nomes dos testes, eu gostei de fazer nomes longos que descrevem a _operação_ realizada e o o resultado _esperado_, como `ao_fazer_x_deve_retornar_y()`, esses nomes parecem deixar bem mais claro o que o código testado faz sem precisar analisar o código dentro dos métodos de teste. Vi [aqui](http://www.codeatest.com/8-erros-comuns-testes-de-unidade/) que é bom que _" Os nomes devem explicar não apenas o cenário sendo testado mas, também, devem explicitar o resultado esperado."_ Se tenho vários asserts, há muita coisa esperada pra por no nome.

Comment: @Douglas obrigado pelas correções. Sobre ser explícita ou implícita: eu não usei nenhum `assertNull` ou `assertEquals` nem nada do gênero. Então no código do método não tem nada explícito para verificar a exceção. Isso fica a cargo da anotação, que é meta-código. Por isso que ainda assim classifiquei como "implícito". Mas, sim, isso pode ser debatido se o conceito de "explícito" e "implícito" estão corretos, mas o uso deles dentro desse contexto de "se é explícito, tem chamada `assert...`" está condizente

Comment: No JUnit 5 existe o assertThrows que substitui essa anotação, então nele com certeza não deve haver mais essa dúvida :D

Comment: @Douglas `assertThrows` é novo para mim. De fato, se houver dois pontos que podem lançar a mesma exceção, a verificação fica mais exata